# Pillow, convert picture to array and back

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need a way how to write a black pixel or not, 1 or 0 to an array. So that later it would be possible to convert back to a picture.

> Image size 28x28

My attempt:

```
def arr_to_image(arr):
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (28, 28), (255, 255, 255, 0))
    pixels = img.load()
    i = 0
    for a in arr:
        line = int(i / 28)
        if a == 1:
            pixels[i % 28, line] = (0, 0, 0)

        i += 1
    img.save('a.png')


image = Image.open('font/a.png')
pix = image.load()

img_arr = []

for y in range(image.size[1]):
    for x in range(image.size[0]):
        s = (pix[x, y][0] + pix[x, y][1] + pix[x, y][2]) // 3 # get middle color
        if s == 0:
            img_arr.append(1)
        else:
            img_arr.append(0)

print(img_arr)
arr_to_image(img_arr)
```

But after all the manipulations, the picture becomes not what it was, why?

[Attempt to return to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsAMT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just change png to bmp. Now all working